# how to tell org-mode to embed my css file on HTML export?

Tags: css, emacs, org-mode

What's the best way to instruct org-mode to embed all the css from my stylesheet into a single HTML file, rather than including a link to it as it does by default?

Comment: Which version of Org-Mode are you running?  With 8.2.1 I get the CSS included in the file by default `C-c C-e C-s h o` (`C-s` for subtree export, my current org file is more than I needed for a test).

Comment: @jonathan-leech-pepin: Thanks. I'm also using org 8.2.1. Here's a minimal org file: http://d.pr/f/jsvk. And here's the resulting HTML file: http://d.pr/f/Nkgl. As you can see, `the #+HTML_HEAD: <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/Users/peter/Dropbox/web-design/custom-css/gmail.css'/>` from the org file gets translated into an external link in the HTML file that looks like: `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/Users/peter/Dropbox/web-design/custom-css/gmail.css' />`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I faced this problem recently and none of the suggestions/answers worked for me. I finally found a solution in [this link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/set-the-background-of-org-exported-code-blocks-according-to-theme), which is to write your own function as follows and put it in you `.emacs` or `init.el` file.

```
(defun my-org-inline-css-hook (exporter)
  "Insert custom inline css"
  (when (eq exporter 'html)
    (let* ((dir (ignore-errors (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))))
           (path (concat dir "style.css"))
           (homestyle (or (null dir) (null (file-exists-p path))))
           (final (if homestyle "~/.emacs.d/org-style.css" path))) ;; <- set your own style file path
      (setq org-html-head-include-default-style nil)
      (setq org-html-head (concat
                           "<style type=\"text/css\">\n"
                           "<!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/\n"
                           (with-temp-buffer
                             (insert-file-contents final)
                             (buffer-string))
                           "/*]]>*/-->\n"
                           "</style>\n")))))

(add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-hook 'my-org-inline-css-hook)
```

Answer (score 12):

There is another solution for that.

In your org file, you can use `#+SETUPFILE: file`, that enables additional in-buffer settings:

```
#+SETUPFILE: style.css.org
```

And in the file `style.css.org`, you can have:

```
#+OPTIONS: org-html-head-include-default-style:nil

#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css">
#+HTML_HEAD:   ...your CSS here...
#+HTML_HEAD: </style>
```

The content of `style.css.org` is:

- `org-html-head-include-default-style:nil` tells to not use the default style.
- `...your CSS here...` is to be replaced by your CSS code. Every line must be prefixed with `#+HTML_HEAD:`.

The advantage of this solution is that you can have a `style.css.org` per file. I personally use the trick to have one `style.css.org` per directory of org files.

Credit goes to  [Paul Provost](https://web.archive.org/web/20130817065759/http://definitelyaplug.b0.cx/post/custom-inlined-css-in-org-mode-html-export/).

*Note that single line CSS is much more performance efficient here than multiple lines CSS.*

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you found a better way but you can do this by just putting your CSS directly into the org-export-html-style variable, wrapping it like this:

```
<style type=\"text/css\">\n <!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/\n **YOUR CSS HERE** \n  /*]]>*  /-->\\n  >/*]]>*/-->\n</style>n</style>
```

Take a look at org-export-html-style-default for an example.

I would also prefer to be able to specify a file in org-export-html-file and have org mode read the file and embed it, but, this way works.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Have you found a way to automatically embed the style sheet on export? I found a great stylesheet [here](https://gist.github.com/mowen/326524) but I have to copy/paste it on every export.

Comment: @Lucas If you set your css into the variable `org-export-html-style` then it should be automatically embedded when you export. Try the following: `M-x customize-variable RET org-export-html-style-default` paste your CSS there  and save it. Make sure that the CSS is wrapped inside a CDATA block as shown above. Basically take the above snippet and replace the **YOUR CSS HERE** part with the raw CSS from the github link you shared.

Comment: @Lucas In recent versions of org-mode it looks like that variable is now called `org-html-style` I just tried with the CSS you shared and it works very nicely and embeds right into the file when you export.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css" />
```

Also take reference from:
http://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html

Comment: That's a link to external stylesheet. I want org-mode to embed css  style information in the head of the HTML file itself.